# Sheep and grass problem

Tags: numerical-methods, word-problem

There's a square shaped grass field and there's a rope in of the corners and a sheep tied to that rope. The rope is so long that the sheep can eat 90% of the field's grass. How long, compared to the diagonal of the square (in percents, accuracy of two numbers will suffice, e.g. 86%) is the rope?
This problem requires a numerical answer.

I've tried using proportionality, in a way that the diagonal corresponds to 100% of the area, and the asked portion of the diagonal corresponds to 90% of the diagonal, but it got me nowhere. I also tried solving it by calculating areas under curves by integrating, but I soon realized there's really no way to do that (at least I couldn't find any way to make it work).

Comment: I've tried using proportionality, in a way that the diagonal corresponds to 100% of the area, and the asked portion of the diagonal corresponds to 90% of the diagonal, but it got me nowhere. I also tried solving it by calculating areas under curves by integrating, but I soon realized there's really no way to do that (at least I couldn't find any way to make it work).

Comment: Cheers! Including that in your question proper (questions can be edited) could encourage a better answer.

Comment: True! I'll do that, thank you (:

Comment: Draw a circle sharing a center with a square but neither the square is entirely in the circle nor the circle is entirely in the square.  What is the area of the part of the circle that is in the square?

Comment: @fleablood How do I calculate the are of the part of the circle that is in the square? I could do it by integrating from -(half of the square's side) to (half of the square's side) between the x-axis and the top side of the square and then multiply that by two, but I don't know the length of the squares side.

Answer (score 1):

If the rope has length $L$, the sheep can go anywhere in the field within $L$ of the corner post. Assume the rope is fixed at $(0,0)$, and the field is $1$x$1$, so the far corner is at $(1,1)$. First note that if the rope has length $1$, the sheep will be able to eat $A(1)=\pi/4$ units squared of grass, which is a bit over $75\%$, so $L>1$. Also, $L<\sqrt2$, because $A(\sqrt2)=1$.

So we need to find the area of the blue region in the following
[image]

and since the field has area $1$, $A(L)$ will be the proportion of the field the sheep can eat. The circular boundary is defined by $x^2+y^2=L^2$.

To find the area, we will calculate the area of the rectangular region and circular part separately. The boundary of the circular region is given by $y=\sqrt{L^2-x^2}$, so the boundary between the rectangular and circular regions is $x=\sqrt{L^2-1}$, and thus the area of the rectangle is $\sqrt{L^1-1}$. For the circular part, we need to calculate an integral, giving the total area as

$$ A(L)=\underbrace{\sqrt{L^2-1}}_{\text{rectangle}}+\underbrace{\int^{1}_{\sqrt{L^2-1}}{\sqrt{L^2-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx}_{\text{circular part}} $$

the integral actually isn't too bad, use the substitution $L\sin(u)=x$ and using the cosine double angle formula, you get

$$ A(L)=\sqrt{L^2-1}+\frac{L^2}{2}\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{L}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{L^2-1}}{L}\right)\right). $$

Now we want to solve $A(L)=k$, where in your case, $k=0.9$. I don't think this equation has an analytic solution, however there are plenty of ways to get a numerical approximation. The simplest for me is to use a Matlab builtin function to find the $L$ that minimises $|A(L)-k|$:

```
%// The area function
A=@(L) sqrt(L^2-1)+L^2/2*(asin(1/L)-asin(sqrt(L^2-1)/L));
%// Since we know 1<L<sqrt(2), use a minimisation function that respects this
L=fminbnd(@(L) abs(A(L)-k),1,sqrt(2))
%// And then find the relative length of the rope compared to the diagonal
percentage=100*L/sqrt(2)
```

This code gives that the length of the rope is $79\%$ of the length of the diagonal of the field.

I also did a quick Monte-Carlo method to give an estimate of the area to check the results:

```
N=5e5;
%// Make some random points, and find the proportion of them that are
%// within L of the post, the area the sheep can eat will be the same
%// proportion of the area of the field
A=nnz(sqrt(sum(rand(2,N).^2))<L)/N
```

and got $A=0.9000$.

Answer (score 0):

Center the field at $(0,0)$ and put the corners at $(\pm1, \pm 1)$ so the area of the field is $4$.

Let the length of the rope by $r$.  If $r \le 1$ then the area grazed by the sheep $\le\pi < 0.9\cdot4$. So $r > 1$.  So the circle described by $r$ will have parts that are outside the field.  Let the area of one of these be $A(r)$ and the area grazed by the sheep will be $\pi\cdot r^2 - 4A(r) = 0.9\cdot 4 = 3.6$.  So we have to find the value or $A(r)$.

We'll find the area of the top one.  The one above $y=1$.

The area is described by an arc of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.  So we want to find the area under the curved bounded by $y=1$.  If $y=1$, $x= \pm\sqrt{r^2 - 1}$  So we need to integrate $y= \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$ from $ \sqrt{r^2 - 1}$ to $-\sqrt{r^2 - 1}$.  That'll be $A(r)$.

Solve for $r$.  Express are in terms of the diagonal.  And you are done.

Comment: It looks like you're assuming the other end of the rope is fastened to a stake in the middle of the field. I think the OP said it was fastened to a corner of the field. But the area the OP wanted then is just the part of the field in the first quadrant, and by symmetry it works out that the radius you compute is the radius OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas here:

[image]

By sine formula,

$$\frac r{\sin{\frac{\pi}4}}=\frac{l\sqrt2}{\sin{(\frac{\pi}4+\phi)}}\implies l=\frac{r(\cos\phi+\sin\phi)}{\sqrt2}$$

Consider the area $A$

\begin{align}
A&=2\cdot\frac{lr}2\sin{(\frac{\pi}4-\phi)}+\frac12 r^2\cdot2\phi\\&=\frac{r^2(\cos\phi+\sin\phi)}{\sqrt2}\cdot[\frac1{\sqrt2}(\cos\phi-\sin\phi)]+r^2\phi\\&=\frac12r^2\cos{(2\phi)}+r^2\phi\\&=r^2(\frac12\cos{(2\phi)+\phi})
\end{align}

Also

$$A=\frac9{10}l^2=\frac9{20}r^2(1+\sin(2\phi))$$

So

$$r^2(\frac12\cos{(2\phi)+\phi})=\frac9{20}r^2(1+\sin(2\phi))$$
$$\frac12\cos{(2\phi)}-\frac9{20}\sin{(2\phi)}-\phi-\frac9{20}=0$$

Solving with Wolfarm Alpha,

$$\phi=0.327197\ldots$$

Hence

$$\frac{r}{l\sqrt2}=\frac1{\cos\phi+\sin\phi}=0.788433\ldots$$